# Absolute positioning does not work with browser resize

Tags: css

I am working on creating a webpage with animated images randomly positioned. My problem is that after a browser re-size images don't re-position within the container.

I have the images with absolute position and the container div with relative position. I keep seeing the image position with respect to the window rather than the parent div.

Here's a jsFiddle example of the problem I see. It has colored divs instead of images, but the problem remains.
http://jsfiddle.net/HMSAM/15/

Appreciate any help in this matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are positioning that children by setting `left: #px` (pixels), and when resizing they keep that property.

If you want to recalculate the position on window resize, just use `left: #%` (percent). Children will keep the value on resize, but it will mean a different "size-in-pixels".

EDIT: Or you can recalculate it, via Javascript, of course.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Changing to % fixed the issue. Thank you so much for your quick response!